# Rotation to landscape not allowed in project, but still rotating on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Universal swift app with 2 device orientations ticked:

Portrait
Upside Down

(I prefer it only to be in portrait mode on all devices)

On my iPhone it never switches to landscape but on an iPad it does.

Any idea why?

Comment: That seems odd, what have you done it lock the application from rotating?

Answer (score 0):

On your plist file under `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` make sure you delete `Landscape (left home button)` and `Landscape (right home button)`.